# Calculate the conjunctive normal form of the following logic expression

Tags: logic, linear-algebra, algebra

I need help in solving this problem:

Calculate the conjunctive normal form of the following logic expression

```
(A and B or C) and (B or not C)
```

Comment: What sort of help do you need?  You just want the answer?  That's not going to be of any long-term help to you.  What have you tried?  What problems did you face?  Do you know what Conjunctive Normal Form is?  Do you know how to expand a logical expression?

Comment: yes, I've expanded the logic expression to : 
(A or B and B or B or B or C) and (not C and A and not C and B or not C or C),
I just need a walkthrough in solving the problem to trace my answers.

Comment: Okay, you clearly need help.  I don't know how you arrived at this, but it is not correct in the slightest.  If you were to make a truth table of this, you would find it not only doesn't match, but is actually equivalent to `false`.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let me change the notation to something more convenient.

```
(A and B or C) and (B or not C)
```

Becomes:

```
(AB + C) (B + C')
```

Now, first you wanna expand this.  The rules are the same as addition and multiplication, so it is essentially the same as a quadratic expansion:

```
ABB + ABC' + CB + CC'
```

Now you can simplify.  The term `ABB` is the same as `AB` (because `B and B` is just `B`).  The term `CC'` is of course always false...

```
AB + ABC' + CB + 0
= AB + ABC' + CB
```

Notice also that `AB + ABC'` can be simplified to `AB`.  This should be obvious, but you can also show it by pulling out the common term `AB`:

```
AB + ABC'
= AB (1 + C')
= AB (1)
= AB
```

Now you have a much simpler expression:

```
AB + CB
```

Once again, you can pull out the common term (`B`):

```
B (A + C)
```

And, how about that..  It's now in conjunctive normal form!  You didn't even need to apply [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

An alternative way to arrive at this is by constructing a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

```
   00  01  10  11  <- AB
  +---+---+---+---
0 | 0   0   0   1
1 | 0   1   0   1

C
```

Pulling the terms out from the map yields `AB + BC`, which is what we arrived at earlier.

Comment: Thank you, I was doing the same but using symbols so I just made things complicated on me ,thanks for your guidance <3